# Removed Comment

Tags: discussion, comments

I wrote a comment on [Citing CPLEX 12.9](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2662/50), but it was removed.

Can somebody tell me why?

It asked for clarification, it was not offensive and, though it was rather long, did not really provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what happened with that. From the history, it doesn't show that the comment was either deleted or reinstated. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

To add some color for a general question of "why a comment is deleted":

A comment can be deleted for various reasons such as:

- Comment contains harassment or abuse
- Comment is unfriendly or unkind
- Comment is outdated or irrelevant
- Any other reason that may need the moderator's attention.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278517/5976530)

> The only purpose of comments is to provide feedback to a question or answer with the goal of improving it. Once this improvement has happened, the value of the comment is nil and it can be removed.

Now to answer your specific question, the contents of your comment are more or less similar to what has provided in all the other answers. So, one can say that in the context (not in isolation) your comment doesn't add any new information and can be flagged as irrelevant.

Comment: I guess I could have left out some parts of the comment already given in answers, but the main purpose of the comment was to ask for clarification about what the OP means by "citing CPLEX". This seems to be legit.

Comment: Yeah, I think what you just said is how it was interpreted and there is nothing wrong for asking for "clarification" (that's the main purpose of the comments after all). In any case, good that you posted the question here for future users.

Comment: Sometimes comments can be less relevant or helpful [yet be kept around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330302/282094) and [sometimes they're encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182295/282094). Some sites collapse them all and some allow > 40 before the 'take it to chat' message prompts the writers. I work hard to write a good question or answer that doesn't require a comment; sometimes I get a thank you and praise (which while *not allowed* is appreciated). $$-$$ **It's great to know that** ***here*** **comments get cleaned up**.